# Is there a better approach than a read-only form to displaying configuration read-only?

Tags: html, forms

I hope that this isn't too hopelessly subjective.

1. ask user to supply a set of configuration options in a form.
2. configure system based on options
3. have a page that display the configuration, read-only, and perhaps a few other facts.

it makes design sense to me to show the config in the same general layout as it was solicited. Further, I like the results of using `fieldset` and `label`. I am, to make it clear, not a highly experienced UI person.

So, I'm inclined to use a `form` with the controls disabled and no submit button at all. Is this hopelessly tasteless / are there common alternatives?

Comment: Maybe also worth asking on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ - I don't know the site at all, but this *should* be on-topic there

Comment: Here we go, more subjective questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, I'm inclined to use a form with the controls disabled and no submit button at all. Is this hopelessly tasteless / are there common alternatives?

I'm not an UX expert either, but it sounds good to me, and the most intuitive: There is no new structure to get used to; the user's eye will immediately recognize the positions from when they filled in the form, which can't be completely wrong.

Seeing as you can address disabled controls using `input[disabled]` in CSS in all modern browsers (no IE6), you also have all the freedom to style the controls if you want to.

Relevant: [Styling disabled form controls with CSS](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/disabled/)

Comment: If it's necessary to target IE6, you _could_ use images instead of form controls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, imo it's a great idea to show the guy's current config in the same format and arrangement as when he set it up. If the user can change *some* of the config setups any time he feels like it, you might want to show those differently (maybe in an edit box :-) from the one-time-only choices he's already made.